# Laravel 403 Forbidden on POST requests on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting, summernote, namecheap

I am getting `403 Forbidden` on `POST` request on laravel application.
Locally it's working but on the server showing 403.
I have used summernote. When I use normal text it works fine but when I use some HTML code like bold, changing font size, adding image then I get 403 after submitting the form.

**Summernote script:**

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // File manager button (image icon)
                const FMButton = function(context) {
                    const ui = $.summernote.ui;
                    const button = ui.button({
                        contents: '<i class="note-icon-picture"></i> ',
                        tooltip: 'File Manager',
                        click: function() {
                            window.open('/file-manager/summernote', 'fm', 'width=1400,height=800');
                        }
                    });
                    return button.render();
                };
                $('#summernote').summernote({

                    toolbar: [
                        // [groupName, [list of button]]
                        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                        ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                        ['color', ['color']],
                        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                        ['height', ['height']],
                        ['fm-button', ['fm']],
                    ],
                    buttons: {
                        fm: FMButton
                    }
                });
            });
            
            // set file link
            function fmSetLink(url) {
                $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", url);
            }
        </script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function sentCompose(Request $request){
     dd($request->all());
   }
```

**When I use normal text on the dump I get:**

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "SGzHLD5Sg8s19Th5RAXodltAzMJU4aQauVr4rfQl"
  "from_email" => null
  "from_name" => null
  "reply_to" => null
  "subject" => null
  "body" => "<p>This is a test message</p>"
  "files" => null
  "schedule" => null
]
```

I am using shared hosting not sure what could create this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to send the same the request again, but change the route to return a string.

just to confirm if laravel blocking anything or if there is a firewall filtering content and displaying the image

Comment: I just returned a string on a new route still showing the same error 403 Forbidden. https://ibb.co/7XnZ58Y

Comment: the image is not loading with me, but is the page a default 403 from laravel or is it a different 403 page, if it's not from laravel there might be a firewall in place that is not allowing the request to pass

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).